# Show that $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence and therefore converges. Proof check

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Let $(x_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ such that there is θ ∈ [0, 1) with
$|x_{n+1} − x_n| ≤ θ^n$
for n ∈ N.

Show that $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence and therefore converges.

Attempt:

claim: $x_n$ is cauchy

Then there exists $|x_m-x_n|$ < E
, where $E>0$

However, since θ^n can be made equal to 0, when $θ \in[0,1)$ we cannot construct an E>0 therefore the sequence is not cauchy.

Comment: It is Cauchy. So, your proof is wrong.

Comment: @amsmath but how though? θ^n can be equal to 0? we can't make an epsilon strictly larger than 0

Comment: If $\theta = 0$, then the sequence is constant and hence Cauchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when we say that there is an number $\theta \in [0,1)$ such that blah blah blah, we mean that $ \theta $ is a fixed number like any other number in [0,1), as, for example, 1/2. Therefore, you can't take $\theta$ in any way you want to make your proof correct, but you need suppose that the fixed $\theta$ just lies in [0,1).

Second, your main objetive is to prove that $\{x_k\}$ is Cauchy provided that there exists **a fixed** $\mathbf{\theta}$ $\in (0,1]$ satisfying $$|x_{n+1} − x_n| ≤ {\theta}^n$$ for every natural number $n$. Aiming that, you need to prove that for every $\epsilon$ greater than zero (not depending on whether it's too big or too close to zero) there exists a natural number $n_{\epsilon}$, i.e., depending just on $\epsilon$, such that for every pair of natural numbers $m,n >n_{\epsilon}$ $$ |x_n - x_m|< \epsilon.$$ Because of that, you can't suppose that there exists $|x_m−x_n| < \epsilon$ at the start of your proof, but you need start with the hypoteses you have, i.e,

$$|x_{n+1} − x_n| ≤ {\theta}^n$$ for every natural number $n$.
Saying all of this, your proof will look like follows.

---

**Proposition**:Let $\{x_k\}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that there exists **a fixed** $\mathbf{\theta}$ $\in (0,1]$ satisfying $$|x_{n+1} − x_n| ≤ {\theta}^n$$ for every natural number $n$, then $\{x_n\}$ is **Cauchy**.

**Proof**: Suppose that there exists **a fixed** $\mathbf{\theta}$ $\in (0,1]$ satisfying $$|x_{n+1} − x_n| ≤ {\theta}^n$$ for every natural number $n$. Then, for every $\epsilon>0$, we can chose $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n>n_0$ follows that $\frac{\theta^n}{1-\theta} \leq \epsilon$, because $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\theta^n}{1-\theta} = 0. $$ Following that, observe that for every pair of positive natural numbers $n, m> n_0$, setting first the case $m>n$, we have 
$$\begin{align}
|x_n-x_m| &= |x_n-x_{n+k}| \\
&\leq |x_n-x_{n+1}|+|x_{n+1}-x_{n+2}|+\cdots+|x_{n+k-1}-x_{n+k}| \\
&\leq \theta^n+\theta^{n+1}+\cdots+\theta^{n+k-1} \\
&< \sum_{j=n}^\infty \theta^j = \frac{\theta^n}{1-\theta}
\end{align}.$$ Then $|x_n-x_m|\leq \epsilon$ for each pair of numbers $n>m>n_0$. For the case $n>m>n_0,$ note that it's just exchange places of $m,n$ in the previous inequations and we will have also $|x_n-x_m|<\epsilon.$ Hence, the sequence is Cauchy.

Comment: I hope you understand my explanation and my wierd english. =)

Answer (score 3):

*Hint*. Let's bound the amount $|x_n-x_m|$. Without loss of generality, assume $m>n$. Then $m=n+k$ for some $k\geq1$. Now, see the following
$$\begin{align}
|x_n-x_m| &= |x_n-x_{n+k}| \\
&\leq |x_n-x_{n+1}|+|x_{n+1}-x_{n+2}|+\cdots+|x_{n+k-1}-x_{n+k}| \\
&\leq \theta^n+\theta^{n+1}+\cdots+\theta^{n+k-1} \\
&< \sum_{j=n}^\infty \theta^j = \frac{\theta^n}{1-\theta}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I don't get it. I'm only working with n+1 not n+k. How can i construct an epsilon? Like I understand the finite sum is less than the infinite sum but I'm not working with an arbitrary k.

Comment: I used your equation to prove the theorem below, Azif00. I don't know if it bothers you, but the proof I give here comes with your credits, ok?

Comment: @Mathissohardlmao You can't only work with $n$ and $n+1$. Cauchy sequences require that for every pair of positive integers $n$ and $m$ greater than some natural number $N$.

Comment: @RenanWillianPrado It's cool. Thanks for helping too :)